# Excel - display Comment for cell that contains ActiveX controls

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I've added several ActiveX "Option Button" Controls into an Excel 2013 cell, and have also added a basic Comment onto this same cell with some text. Via the default behavior, when a user mouses over this cell the Comment will be displayed.

The issue I'm facing is that the Comment is not displayed when the user mouses over the ActiveX Controls (but it works anywhere in the cell outside the ActiveX controls). Does anyone know a simple workaround to make a Comment's mouse-over behavior work for the entire cell, including when their hovering over the embedded ActiveX control? Thanks!

Comment: Would it be sufficient if the comment would appear if the option button gets the focus? Because there is a MouseMove event but no secure MouseOut detection for Controls. So we could show the comment on MouseMove but not secure hide it on MouseOut. With the focus there are GotFocus and LostFocus events.

Comment: I don't think showing/hiding the comment with Focus events would get the intended effect, because doesn't getting focus require the user to actually click the control? Thank you for the feedback nevertheless, it's a good option to consider. Although programmatic VBA solutions could work, I was really trying to check if there's any sort of property/configuration that can be set such that the ActiveX control won't take precedence over the data cell when hovering over it (e.g., layering).